# Can't Delete Folder/Files on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, command-line, file-permissions, windows-server-2012

I have a folder with two ISO files in it that I don't need anymore but I can't delete the folder. I am an Administrator and owner of the files.

When I delete using Windows Explorer the files disappear, but as soon as I refresh they return. When I try to delete from the Command Prompt using the arguments `/F` and `/Q` I get the error:

> Access is denied.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you see the files in the command prompt?

Comment: @Tog Yes, if I use dir they are there and if I hit tab they come up